# Strategic and tactical ideas for White in this KIA game

Tags: opening, kings-indian-attack

What are the good strategic and tactical plans for White in this position?

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
1. e4 e6 2. d3 d5 3. Nd2 c5 4. g3 Nc6 5. Bg2 Nf6 6. Ngf3 Be7 7. O-O O-O 8. Re1 Qc7 9. e5 Nd7 10. Qe2 f5 11. exf6 Nxf6
```

I wonder what should I do with the Black's c, d, and e pawns. How to prevent them from pushing forward and after preventing them from pushing forward, what should be the next plan for White?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had studied the KIA for a time in the early'90's, although with mixed results, so I don't claim to be an expert on the subject.  In this position 12.c3 would constrain the Black "d" pawn, but I think I would initially play 12.Bh3 to restrain the more important "e" pawn, which is currently backward on the open file.  Then if 12..., e5; 13.Bxc8 & 14.Nxe5 would win it. Or if Black decided to reinforce it by 12..., Nd8, then 13.Ne5 could occupy the hole and then support this N with subsequent 14. Ndf3 and 15.Bf4 moves.  And since the purpose of the KIA is a kingside attack, you would probably subsequently want to mobilize your kingside pawns once you had this center control.  I hope these suggestions are of some value.

Comment: Thanks @CConero. Great idea! I will analyze some variations related to it and post my update.

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary/good to play 9.e5? The centre gets liquidated quite quickly after that. What about 9.c3 with the typical KIA ideas -

1) e5 (which can now be supported by d4) followed by h4, Nf1-h2-g4

2) a4 preparing Nc4 if c4 ever becomes available eg 9... de 10. de e5 11.a4

3) Qc2

EDIT having checked on 365chess.com 9.c3 is indeed a good alternative but in the diagram position 12.Bh3 is often played as the bishop is better on that diagonal whereas Black is not really threatening ...e5.

Comment: There are many good variations related to e5 so it is the variation that I always play in the tournament. I haven't explored yet other variations that do not include the e5 push.

Answer (score 0):

The e6 pawn is weak, protected by white bishop. Attack and sacrifice your white bishop with check from Bh3. Finally position is Qe6, with 1 pawn advantage. Notice the black bishop is stuck and must be developed.